# switch off backup and restore history in SQL-server

Tags: backup, settings, sql-server-2017

I have a question concerning SQL-server 2017.  I automatically back-up all my databases once every hour. But over time this causes bloating of the MSDB database, because for all my databases (many) the backup and restore history is written to the MSDB database. I have no need for this data and it just makes it neccesary for me to regularly delete the backup en restore data to shrink the MSDB database back to normal proportions.

Actually  this is a waste of my time as this data is never used for anything. So I was wondering if it is possible to switch off the backup and restore history feature. It would be a time saver for me, hence the question.

Comment: I must admit, if you are that strapped for storage space, the msdb database isn't the place I would start looking. How *big* are you saying your backup tables are?

Comment: I keep the MSDB to max 3GB. When it reaches that value, I start to delete the backup history and shrink the db back to approx. 250 MB.  But my point is it is filling up with useless data (at least for me it is). I would think you could switch off this pointless filling of the MSDB, but I cannot find a setting for it.